# blur event for mobile web applications

Tags: onblur, mobile-webkit

I'm creating a mobile web application that will run on webkit browsers. The thing is I have a textbox, whose value needs to be validated after the user has typed in some value.

Is there a blur event for input elements in mobile browsers? I've tried searching for it on the web, but couldn't find the right reference.

Regards,

Erwin